# redirect to url and set variable in template

Tags: plugin-development

In a plugin, I am trying to redirect to a url, and set some values on the template. It's not working. Here is a simplified (not working) test case:

Template lives at templates/test.twig:

```
someVar is defined? {{ someVar is defined ? 'yes' : 'no' }}

<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  {{ getCsrfInput() }}
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="site/test">
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/test">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Controller code (which does get called):

```
public function actionTest() {
    craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(array(
        'someVar' => 23
    ));
    $this->redirectToPostedUrl();
}
```

What I expect, is that when I first visit the page, `someVar` isn't defined, but when I submit the form and revist the page, `someVar` will be defined (and equal 23). But it is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reload the form, you don't need to (indeed, shouldn't) redirect to the posted URL. That's why the form's `action` attribute is empty.

This should work:

```
public function actionTest() {
    craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(array(
        'someVar' => 23
    ));
}
```

Comment: The problem with that I am filtering and paginating a bunch of entries. I might be on page 3 of pagination, and what the form does is change the filter conditions, and now I want to go back to page 1 (which is a different url)

Comment: Ah. In that case `setRouteVariables` isn't of much use to you, as the data doesn't persist across page requests. Your best bet is to store the data in the session.

Comment: Storing it in a session was the way to go. Do you want to write that up as an answer for me, and I will accept it?